# Node-red "serial port temporarily unavailable, cannot lock serial port" problem

Tags: locking, port, node-red

I am trying to control some sensors and a hydraulic system and a vane with a servo via raspberry pi and arduino. I use serial node to communicate with arduino. One serial node for incoming data from arduino and one for sending data to arduino over node-red. The problem is node-red cannot lock the usb serial port and cannot communicate with arduino while arduino ide can do it. In Node-red forum They have advised me to closed other programs that can use the serial port. I have closed arduino ide and reset Pi 4 but nothing changed. I have restart them but problem still stands.

Is there a way to solve this locking problem?

How can I see the serial ports and the programs that use the ports?

Can I prevent them to use these ports with a javascript or a python function code?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual error messages and describe in detail exactly what leads to the problem. Are you trying (or have you tried) to run both Node-RED and the IDE at the same time?

Comment: "Error: Error Resource temporarily unavailable Cannot lock port". I have closed arduino ide and tried it again but result was same.

Comment: Have you looked in  the `/var/lock` directory to see if there is a stale lock file?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and fix it. There is no other program or software was using serial port /dev/ttyACM0 was being used by another flow in a passive node-red window. I have to delete that page and nodes.